# css dynamic background image positioning

Tags: css, dynamic, background-image, positioning

I have some dynamic images as a background for some divs. Those have variable widths and heights. In front of each such a div i have a radio button. There is a way to align through css each div to be exactly at the middle referring to the radiobutton in front of it? I cannot use fixed background height since there are dynamic and the height are different. I was trying to put `background-size: 100% 100%;` or `background-size: auto;`
Doesn't work
Any help is more than welcome, thanks!!!

Comment: please show a fiddle with your actual markup

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jrrtzgyt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
background-position: center center;
```

## =====

**UPDATE:**

It's a lot easier working with your fiddle!

Try this:

```
div.VISA_logo {
    background: url("http://www.globalworkandtravel.com/sites/all/modules/customshare/includes/facebook.png") no-repeat;
}

div.VISA_CARTE_BLEUE_logo{
    background: url("http://www.discoverireland.ie/App_Themes/DiscoverIreland/images/discoveries/button-add-trip-small.png") no-repeat;
}

div.MasterCard_logo{
    background: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/sugarstats/s3_avatars/7287/1234222094_norm.jpg") no-repeat;
}

div.AMEX_logo{
    background: url("http://www.uappointment.com/images/google-small-icon.png") no-repeat;
}

div.PAYPAL_logo{
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/EqgOS.png") no-repeat;
}

div.VISA_logo,
div.MasterCard_logo,
div.PAYPAL_logo,
div.VISA_CARTE_BLEUE_logo,
div.MasterCard_DE_FR_UK_logo,
div.AMEX_logo {
    width: 105px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    height: 42px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
    background-position:0 center;
}
```

Comment: Now you've posted a fiddle, I've updated my answer. See above.